# Securing Calls to APIs | Azure AD Apps in Different Directory

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-logic-apps

If my logic app is in one directory and my Azure AD Apps are in a different directory, will the following guide work?  [Secure calls to your custom APIs from logic apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-custom-api-authentication)

---

My Logic App is defined in: myLogicApp.onmicrosoft.com

My 2 Azure AD Apps are defined in: myB2CTenant.onmicrosoft.com

Will that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great idea ! I did a test and it worked.

The difference is in the configuration of the GUID (Directory ID) in the Issuer Url:

> Under Issuer Url, copy and save just the GUID for Part 3. You can also
>   use this GUID in your web app or API app's deployment template, if
>   necessary.
>
> **This GUID is your specific tenant's GUID ("tenant ID") and should
>   appear in this URL: `https://sts.windows.net/{GUID}`**

So, I create one Web App in my A tenant, and create one App registraton in B2C tennat.

Each configuration is as same as the guide. But when you set the GUID in `https://sts.windows.net/{GUID}`, the GUID should be your B2C tenant ID(Directory ID).

Hope this helps!